# msal.js in React - Azure authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-ad-msal

I got error but all access in azure is ok. maybe my endpoint is wrong? Have you got any idea?

Error APP_TEST needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I use this

example

TenanId = 11111111
ClientID = 22222222

```
export const msalConfig = {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111',
    clientId: '22222222',
    redirectUri: document.getElementById('root').baseURI
};
```

and

```
 msalAuth = new UserAgentApplication({
        auth: msalConfig,
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open up your application `22222222` in AAD and grant the permissions that were added. See this screen:

[image: AAD Screen]